# Mutliple IF statements results in False instead of Blank ("")

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

Multiple IF statements are giving me a FALSE response instead of the requested BLANK.

I figured that the last of the IF statements that has a "" would give BLANK if none of the conditions are met.

I've tried isolating each IF to see if I'm missing a statement but I don't see it.

Here is my formula:

`=IF((LEFT(D5,2))=H2,IF(C5="Yearly",G5,IF(C5="Fixed Monthly",G5/12,"")))`

How can I modify this formula so that it does not give me a FALSE and instead gives me a BLANK as requested on the 3rd IF statement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may an else condition to the first if statement:

```
Here is my formula:

=IF(LEFT(D5,2)=H2, IF(C5="Yearly",
                      G5,
                      IF(C5="Fixed Monthly",G5/12,"")),
                   "")    <-- add this
```

My guesd is that because you did not specify an explicit else condition, Excel is defaulting to showing `FALSE`.

Comment: You got it! It works. Thank you so much @Tim Biegeleisen